# Terraform - Delete all resources except one

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure

I have a Terraform 0.11 project with 30-40 different resources. I would like to delete all of them except a few - and those few are logically related to each other.

I was looking for something close to `terraform destroy --except=resource-id` but that of course doesn't exist.

Is there a way to achieve that without too much scripting (Terraform admins have various OSs)? Would using modules make that process easier perhaps?

Comment: The answer is to not structure your code base this way. Things in the same directory should all be creatable or destroyable at the same time. Part applying changes is an escape hatch, not something to rely on.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR This makes sense. I would accept this answer, if you can write it up

Comment: It feels like it might be a duplicate, let me have a dig around, otherwise I'll write it up as an answer here.

Comment: what about eips? say for example you had these whitelisted and don't want to destroy them because you need a change control elsewhere, you set Terraform to create and mark wit prevent_destroy, all prevent_destroy does here is to fail your terraform destroy command. You could create the eip outside terraform and just manage the association, but both feel like this could be handled better

Comment: None of these answers is satisfying. I have a set of related infrastructure AND I want a couple items to remain after destroy AND they should remain in TF's state. Use cases: some S3 buckets (I recently "lost" an S3 bucket name for a transient test environment due to namesquatting); and ACM certs which require manual validation with non-AWS DNS provider. For environments that come and go (i.e. test environments taken down overnight to reduce cost). I don't think this is unreasonable.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There is no `--except` feature in `terraform destroy` command currently. If you really want to do that, and you know what you are doing, here is the workaround.

```
# list all resources
terraform state list

# remove that resource you don't want to destroy
# you can add more to be excluded if required
terraform state rm <resource_to_be_deleted> 

# destroy the whole stack except above excluded resource(s)
terraform destroy
```

#### So why do these commands work for your idea?

[The state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/) (*.tfstate) is used by Terraform to map real world resources to your configuration, keep track of metadata.

`terraform state rm` cleans a record (resource) from the state file (*.tfstate) only. It doesn't destroy the real resource.

Since you don't run `terraform apply` or `terraform refresh`, after `terraform state rm`, terraform doesn't know the excluded resource was created at all.

When you run `terraform destroy`, it has no detail about that excluded resource’s state and will not destroy it. It will destroy the rest.

By the way, later you still have chance to import the resource back with `terraform import` command if you want.

Comment: This now orphans the state of the resource that's not deleted so Terraform won't manage it any more which isn't really what the OP wanted. You _could_ import it again after deleting everything else but in general partial apply and destroy is a bad idea.

Comment: This is a decent workaround for my situation. Not ideal, as ydaetskcor says, but good enough.

Comment: its working fine

Comment: what would the `import` be? `terraform import <resource_to_be_reimported>` ?

Comment: Import command would be different to each resource, you need take reference from the terraform document.

Answer (score 13):

Targetting each resource (while skipping over the data resources) except the one you want is probably the only way atm:

```
#! /bin/bash

while read -r resource; do
    terraform destroy -target="$resource"
done < <(terraform state list | grep -vE "^data\." | grep -vE "dont_remove|also_important")
```

Comment: If you're using a module the "^data\." pattern needs to be "\.data\."

Comment: And (obviously, but I missed it!) its not use TF's dependency graph, so this probably won't work except in simple cases.

Answer (score 7):

To delete all your stack except some resources, you need to:

1. Create a backup of your current state : `terraform state pull > bkup.json`
2. List all your resources : `terraform state list`
3. "rm" the resources that **you want to keep** : `terraform state rm "aws_myresource"`. It will not delete the resource in your cloud, but only from the terraform perspective.
4. Destroy your stack : it will be delete from the cloud all your resources except the ones you "rm" just before. `terraform destroy`
5. You now have an empty state (0 resources). Save it in order to be able to edit it : `terraform state pull > state-to-edit.json`
6. Edit the `state-to-edit.json` by adding resources object `{}` from the `bkup.json` in the `.resources[]` block. You also need to increment by 1 the `.serial` value
7. Push the modified state : `terraform state push ./state-to-edit.json`
8. You can verify with `terraform plan` or `terraform state list` that you still have the wanted resources & deleted all the others.

Comment: This is the only answer that does what the OP asked. I'm just sad this is necessary. See also this nearly four year old [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23547).

Comment: Thank you @ChuckBatson, I added it in the issue for visibility purpose. Hopes it helps people.

Comment: I wonder why terraform was created with so much hate in one's soul.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit of a different work around. The resources I do not want to delete with "terraform destroy" I create as "null_resource" using a provisioner with CLI. You can still use your variables in terraform as well.

for example (Create a resource group, but it is persistent due to null_resource)

```
resource "null_resource" "backend-config" {
        provisioner "local-exec" {
        command     = <<EOT
    az group create --location ${var.Location} --name ${var.Resource_group_name} --tags 'LineOfBusiness=${var.Lob}' 'Region=${var.Region}' 'Purpose="Terraform-Primary-Resource-Group-${var.Lob}'
    EOT
        interpreter = ["Powershell", "-Command"]
      }
    }
```

Now if you destroy the resources using terraform destroy.
Any null_resource will remain intact.

Answer (score 1):

[BMW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55271805/3377926) is best if you just need to destroy things, *and not change the code*. That is, if you intend to bring those resources back up at some later time.

If you just want to remove the resources, the proper solution is to remove the Terraform definitions you wish to destroy, and then do a normal `terraform apply`. Just as you would for *adding* a resource.

(An old question, I know, but I was surprised to not see anyone mention alternative. The OP's use case seems to be covered by the other answers, so this answer is for others stumbling in here.)

Answer (score 0):

1. List resources:

   ```
   terraform state list

     data.terraform_remote_state.rg
     azurerm_postgresql_database.postgresql_database
     azurerm_postgresql_server.postgresql_server
   ```
2. Remove resource

   ```
   terraform destroy -target azurerm_postgresql_database.postgresql_database -auto-approve
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this has already been covered quite well, but I wanted to share a extended shell script to tackle this problem. Here is a short shell script that removes resources from the terraform state and then after shows the new terraform state list before it then asks to terraform destroy the remaining resources:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Function to display help message
show_help() {
    echo "Usage: $0 <directory> <resource_to_remove1> [resource_to_remove2 ...]"
    echo "This script removes specified resources from Terraform's state in the given directory."
    echo "It then destroys all other resources managed by Terraform in that state."
    echo
    echo "Arguments:"
    echo "  <directory>               Path to the directory with Terraform configuration."
    echo "  <resource_to_remove>...   One or more resources to remove from Terraform state."
    echo
    echo "Example:"
    echo "  $0 /path/to/terraform/dir resource_to_remove1 resource_to_remove2"
    exit 0
}

# Check for '-h' or '--help' arguments
if [ "$1" == "-h" ] || [ "$1" == "--help" ]; then
    show_help
fi

# Check if at least two arguments are provided (directory and at least one resource)
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect usage. For help, use: $0 -h"
    exit 1
fi

# First argument is the directory
terraform_directory=$1

# Change to the specified Terraform directory
cd "$terraform_directory" || exit

# Remaining arguments are the resources to remove
resources_to_remove=("${@:2}")

# Remove specified resources from the state
for resource in ${resources_to_remove[@]}; do
    terraform state rm "$resource"
done

# List and destroy the remaining resources
echo "Final state before destruction:"
terraform state list
echo "Proceeding with destruction..."
terraform destroy
```

Answer (score -2):

terraform destroy -target RESOURCE_TYPE.NAME -target RESOURCE_TYPE2.NAME

Comment: can you comment whats wrong on my answer?

Comment: question is asking how to destroy all resources but one, you are showing (without explaining) how to destroy single resources. If someone follows blindly your answer he/she would destroy just the resource he/she wants to keep