# How not to destroy the imported resource group in Terraform with Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am currently writing a Terraform file which should create all required resources in Azure in a specific resource group. As I do not have the permissions to create resource groups I imported an existing resource group following this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-manage-existing-azure-resource-groups-using-terraform/ba-p/1648135).

Now the problem is that when I run `terraform destroy`, the system also wants to delete the resource group as it was included as a resource.
Is there a simple way I can tell Terraform to destroy all created resources except the imported resource group? Or another way to approach this problem?

I tried the [lifecycle variable `prevent_destroy`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#prevent_destroy) but it prevents any resource from being destroyed.
The solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265203/terraform-delete-all-resources-except-one) does not really work for me as I do not want to use multiple commands as this adds the risk of human error. What I am basically looking for is a way to label the resource group in the Terraform file in a way that it is not deleted.

Comment: if you dont want to manage it, why import?

Comment: @gsb22 Because he needs to _refer_ to it but he doesn't want Terraform to create and/or destroy it. I had the same use case recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refer to a resource but not have Terraform manage the lifecycle of it (either at all or just in that specific Terraform workspace) then you can use [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html).

In your case you could replace the [`azure_resource_group` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group) with the [`azure_resource_group` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/resource_group).